# How to add values of an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with list of values like the following

```
[
  {
    "name":"x",
    "type":"deposit",
    "deposit_amount":100
  }
  {
    "name":"x",
    "type":"withdraw",
    "withdraw_amount":10
  }
  {
    "name":"y",
    "type":"deposit",
    "deposit_amount":20  
  }
  {
    "name":"y",
    "type":"withdraw",
    "withdraw_amount":20  
  }
]
```

I need to add "deposit_amount" of objects having type as "deposit" and  "withdraw_amount" of objects having type as "withdraw".

I have tried using ng-init using ng-repeat

```
 <th ng-show="$last" ng-init="obj.total.deposit_amount = obj.total.deposit_amount + data.deposit_amount">Amount Collected : {{obj.total.deposit_amount}}</th>

 <th ng-show="$last" ng-init="obj.total.withdraw_amount = obj.total.withdraw_amount + data.withdraw_amount">Amount Withdrawn :{{obj.total.withdraw_amount}}</th>
```

When I use this I got the expected one,but each time I click on search the total values get updating.

Any help would be Appreciated.Thanks

Comment: create a function, call your function to update your data stored inside a variable with array.push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle that with javascript like this or something.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{"name":"x","type":"deposit","deposit_amount":100},
                          {"name":"x", "type":"withdraw", "withdraw_amount":10},
                          {"name":"y", "type":"deposit", "deposit_amount":20},
                          {"name":"y", "type":"withdraw", "withdraw_amount":20}
                        ];
    $scope.totalDeposit = 0;
    $scope.totalWithdraw = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj) {
        if(obj.type == 'deposit') {
            $scope.totalDeposit += obj.deposit_amount;
        }
        else if(obj.type == 'withdraw') {
            $scope.totalWithdraw += obj.withdraw_amount;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>Amount Collected : {{totalDeposit}}</div>
    <div>Amount Withdrawn : {{totalWithdraw}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var x={};  x.test='xyz';  console.log(x);`



--> obj.total.deposit_amount = 'x'